# how to convert seconds to duration using mm:ss format in Google Looker Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

let say I have a numeric metric `605` (seconds) then I want to create a new field which is  a duration in `mm:ss` format. so for metric `605` then I want to get `10:05` as a new calculated field

how to do that in Google Looker Studio?

Comment: Do you need this `mm:ss` format just for the look of it OR intend to use it for any other calculations/time series charts?! If its the latter, setting the field type of the metric to "Duration (sec.)" will give you the hh:mm:ss format value but since you specifically asked for mm:ss just wanted to get clarity on the core use of this calculated field...

Comment: I need it to be displayed as a chart (scorecard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're consindering only `MM:SS` part, you can consider below calculated field

```sql
FORMAT_DATETIME(
  '%M:%S', 
  DATETIME(
    1970, 1, 1, 0, 
    CAST(duration / 60 AS INT64),
    duration - CAST(duration / 60 AS INT64) * 60
  )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
CONCAT(CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(ROUND(seconds/60,0),"\\d{1}")THEN CAST(concat(0,ROUND(seconds/60,0)) AS TEXT) ELSE CAST(ROUND(seconds/60,0) AS TEXT) END,
        ":",
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(seconds-(60*ROUND(seconds/60,0)),"\\d{1}") THEN CAST(concat(0,seconds-(60*ROUND(seconds/60,0))) AS TEXT) ELSE CAST(seconds-(60*ROUND(seconds/60,0)) AS TEXT) END)
```

[image]